# TypeScript compilation error, importing non default interface with curly braces

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-typings

When compiling my TypeScript project, the compiler is throwing the following error:

```
node_modules/@types/domutils/index.d.ts:6:10 - error TS2614: Module '"../../domhandler/lib"' has no exported member 'DomElement'. Did you mean to use 'import DomElement from "../../domhandler/lib"' instead?
```

The offending line is:

```
import { DomElement } from "domhandler";
```

The problem is, in the typing file it is trying to import from, the DomElement interface is a non default exported interface as follows:

```
export interface DomElement {
    attribs?: {[s: string]: string};
    children?: DomElement[];
    data?: any;
    name?: string;
    next?: DomElement;
    parent?: DomElement;
    prev?: DomElement;
    type?: string;
}
```

If I remove the curly braces it does in fact work, but that seems problematic to me:

1. I was under the impression that only default exports can be imported without curly braces. Why is this import **required** without curly braces?
2. This issue is occurring in type definitions in the `node-modules` folder as provided by *DefinitelyTyped*. I do not want to change a dependency file. There are no related open issues in Github, so I assume it does work. In fact it works for a colleague with an older version of Node (v8) but that doesn't seem like it should make a difference.

Versions:

- Node.js - 12.14.0
- List item
- TypeScript 3.7.2 (also tested not working on 3.7.4)
- Type definitions for domhandler 2.4 (https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/domhandler)
- Type definitions for domutils 1.7 (https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/domutils)

**UPDATE**

Here is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": [
        "node_modules/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Experiencing the same issue when using `sanitize-html` as its dependency tree is `sanitize-html` -> `htmlparser2` -> `domutils` -> `domhandler`. The configuration (with typescript 3.6.4) worked in node 8 before upgrading to node 12.

Comment: Could you please check in your `npm-shrinkwrap.json` or `package-lock.json` if there are multiple versions of `domutils` in there? And also, which dependencies are pulling in `domutils` in which versions?

Answer (score 2):

Based on info from [aluanhaddad at GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21344#issuecomment-361495894) I managed to get it compiling (and working), though I don't like the solution (because it's actually turning any checking for that module off).

I have removed typings to sanitize-html (and related domhandler etc.). TSC cries that it doesn't know "sanitize-html" module, so I've added a dummy module declaration inside my src folder.

src/sanitize-html.d.ts

```
declare module 'sanitize-html';
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "lib": [
    "es6",
    "dom"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*",
    "index.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

build command:

```
tsc
```